# Rails : Passing Variable to new controller method from view

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I just want to knwo if it's possible to pass a variable to a 'new' controller method when using a helper.

I thought it was something like that :

```
link_to "New", new_controller_path, method: :get, var: var
```

With a hash params like this params[... var: var].

Best regards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

yes, just make sure you put the params as part of the url:

```
link_to "Create User", new_controller_path(email: "hi@email.com", password: "secret")
```

Comment: Thank you very much ! The only thing i was missing was the syntax actually ^^. Yes, I edited my question because of your comment, thx for the rigor ;)